# pagination with dots in middle generate with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css, pagination

Im trying to create pagination using PHP but I have issue with quantity of page.

my pagination created used

```
foreach(range(1, $pager) as $i){    
                echo '<span class="pagination-num" data-pager="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</span>';              
            }
```

the problem comes when the range is too large. like on the image below. variable `$pager` contains a dynamic value. `$pager` counts how many pages should created from quantity of the content.

I set 10 content per page, so if there is 100 content:

```
$pager = ceil($content / 10);
```

[image: my results pagination]

it's there any way to edit pagination with dots. (next and prev I created using custom Jquery).

Comment: Any chance you're using one of the major PHP frameworks?  Most have pagination functionality built in.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you need to set items per page for example 10 items per page

```
<?php
$ipp = 10; //Item Per Page
if(isset($_GET["page"]) AND $_GET["page"] > 0){
    $page_number = $_GET['page']; // page number
}
else{$page_number = 1;}
$total_items = 100; //total items
$total_pages = ceil($total_items/$ipp); //total pages
$page_position = (($page_number-1) * $ipp); //page position
?>
```

just in case if you are using sql:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE --something-- ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT {$page_position}, {$ipp}"
```